# Rename/move file on FTP server after import activity is done

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

I am using the Automation Studio to initiate an Import of a file from an FTP server into a data extension in ExactTarget. I need to keep the file once it is done the Import, however it needs to be named something else on the FTP server so it is not reused. How would I go about doing this? There is a question similar to this on the stack exchange, however it was said to be incorrect by some of the comments. I tried using a File Transfer activity to re-upload the file, however this does not allow renaming (as far as I know).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the move file functionality. Please see below

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230276&type=1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't.

It may be worthwhile to ask SFMC Support if there are any special File Transfer business rules that can be enabled to do something like this.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that. Thank you. Do you have any other ideas for preventing  file reuse? E.g. if the files that will be downloaded from the SFTP server on a scheduled basis were of the format Data_File%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%, is there another way to make it so ExactTarget does not use the same date everytime, and always takes the latest one?

Comment: There are expiration settings on both File [Imports](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-an-import-definition.html) and [Transfers](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/).  Keep in mind they are based on UTC time, per the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Once you've imported the file into your target DE, couldn't you import the file to a temporary DE (overwrite), export it with a different name (using not only **%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%** but also **%%Hour%%%%Minute%%%%Second%%** so it's going to be unique every time the automation runs), then transfer it to the FTP folder of your choice? I'm not sure of your exact requirements, but it seems like it could meet your needs.

If you're creating the initial import file via an extract activity, then it may solve your problem to simply add **%%Hour%%%%Minute%%%%Second%%** to your naming convention. I wasn't sure if you're doing that or importing it from an external FTP server.

Comment: I am getting the initial import file from an FTP server. The problem is that I need to be able to not only export the file to a new location in the FTP, but also remove the original.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only remove files via FTP software or waiting 21 days for the file to be removed automatically.